# What does unicode character &#10; represent?

Tags: html, xml, unicode, character-encoding

The unicode is `&#10;` and it's being used in an XML document.

Comment: That's not unicode, it's a numeric character entity.

Comment: Agreed.  Read the XML standard (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/), in particular section 4.1 ("Character and Entity References").

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Check the chart: [unicodelookup.com](http://unicodelookup.com/#&#10;/1)

It is the Line Feed character.

Answer (score 24):

It's the ASCII character LF, Line Feed.

Some systems (e.g. Windows) use the combination CR+LF, `&#13;&#10;`, for line break, some systems (e.g. Linux) use only LF as line break, some systems (e.g. Macintosh before OS X) use only CR as line break.

So, only a LF character in an XML value would be a line break from a Linux system (or similar).

Comment: This is an old post but just to point out that Macs used CR back in the days of OS 9 in the 90s. These days they use LF, since the operating system is based on Unix.

Answer (score 10):

There are some great lookup tools on the Web:

- [Unicode Lookup](http://unicodelookup.com/)
- [Uncode Character Search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm)

Answer (score 2):

It's the newline character.

Comment: While that is correct, what would be more helpful is a reference so he can look up entities himself in the future.