# How to convert xml to csv using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

Hi i do have following xml code:
Then i need to convert those xml to csv format with header title is show.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>

  <portfolio>

     <stock exchange="nasdaq"> 
     <name>zaffymat inc</name> 
     <symbol>ZFFX</symbol> 
     <price>92.250</price> 
     </stock> 

     <stock exchange="nyse"> 
     <name>zacx corp</name> 
     <symbol>ZCXM</symbol> 
     <price>28.875</price> 
     </stock> 

     <stock exchange="nasdaq"> 
     <name>zysmergy inc</name> 
     <symbol>ZYSZ</symbol> 
     <price>20.313</price> 
     </stock> 

  </portfolio>
```

How can i transform xml above to csv like below output via xsl?

```
"Name";"Price"
"zaffymat inc";"92.250"
"zysmergy inc";"20.313"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XSLT to get your desired output:

```
  <xsl:template match="portfolio">
    <xsl:text>"Name";"Price"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="stock">
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      <xsl:text>";</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanxs Navin.Its work .I add <xsl:for-each select="//stock[@exchange='nasdaq']"> to filter the output.I also add <br/>&#10; to make a new line. =)

Comment: For those who may search it: `&#10`; is `\n` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025265/what-does-unicode-character-10-represent

Answer (score 0):

This is my last script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="portfolio">

<xsl:text>"Name"</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>"Price"</xsl:text><br/>&#10;

<xsl:for-each select="//stock[@exchange='nasdaq']">

<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

<xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="price"/>
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text><br/>&#10;

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Its work fine to filter out the info and making new line for csv output! =)