# Javafx fxml file TextArea line break and tab in text

Tags: xml, javafx, textarea, edit, fxml

How to edit `text` in the `TextArea` in `.fxml file as such I can use *line breaks* and *tabs*.
The Textarea is predefined and can not be edited.

Images to support

**FXML File**

[image: FXML File]

**The View**

[image: The View]

Comment: Edit `.fxml` file in `TextArea`?

Comment: \n and \t are not works.

Comment: TextArea accepts Enter and Tab. I am not sure if I understand your question

Comment: Yes I know but I do this is fxml file and there not work. If I write \n or \t then just write text \n \t.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to directly use the text you can use something :

```
<TextArea prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="${'Multi\nLine\tTab'}" />
```

In case you want to use in Scene Builder, you can switch to multi-line mode.

[image]

Switching to multi-line mode, scene builder will insert:

```
&#10; for \n 
&#9;  for \t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Itachi Where can I find a list of these `&#10;, &#9;, etc.`? Tried googling something like`FXML escape codes` but couldn't find a list. Thanks.

Comment: Those are Line Feed characters. For more information, go through [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025265/what-does-unicode-character-10-represent).

Comment: Lets say I want define a variable:
`<String fx:id="LABEL_01" fx:value="${'Multi\nLine\tTab'}"`

How to use it now?

Comment: Got it, instead of using `'\n'` I need to use `'&#xD;'`. Then `fx:value="Multi&#xD;line"` and then I can use this variable like: `text="$LABEL_01"`.