# Split string in php with new line

Tags: php

I've a problem with string spliting.

```
<?php
    $blackShopArray = preg_split("~[|!,\s\n\b]+~", $cfg['options']['bslist']);
    $blackShopColumn = '';
    foreach($blackShopArray as $shop){
        $blackShopColumn .= $shop . "<br/>";
    }
    echo $blackShopColumn;
?>
```

This code can't split string by a newline symbol. How to fix it?

Comment: What is `$cfg['options']['bslist']`?  `\s` matches newline `\n` and `\r`.

Comment: And imploding on `<br />` would be the same.  Or `preg_replace` with `<br />`.

Comment: @pragmus did you solve it yet?

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I just looked my code page and it shows string is deleted by &#10; symbols instead of newline.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ, no

Comment: I will answer you if that fix the problem let me know if not let me know to so I can further optimize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` (newline) and `\r` (return) control characters are the same as 
`&#10` and `&#13` ASCII control characters in HTML which is 
`CR` (Carriage return) and `LF` (Line feeed).

But when we want check those out in `Regex` (regular expression) then they are different. In this case to match those in preg_split.

Therefore we could replace `&#10` and `&#13` with empty string and use `str_split` in stead. I am pretty sure it can be done different ways.

Here is my approach:

```
<?php
$cfg = "Some text will &#13;&#10;go in new line";

$cfg = str_replace("&#10;", "", $cfg);
$cfg = str_replace("&#13;", "", $cfg);
$blackShopArray = str_split($cfg);
$blackShopColumn = '';
foreach ($blackShopArray as $shop)
{
    $blackShopColumn .= $shop . "<br/>";
}
echo $blackShopColumn;
?>
```

#### Some references:

- [What does unicode character &#10; represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025265/what-does-unicode-character-10-represent)
- [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)
- [What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n)
- [ASCII table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/carriage-return-ascii-code-13.html)
- [More](http://ascii.cl/control-characters.htm) ASCII table
- Help you check your Regex [online](https://regex101.com/)